# Как остановить выполнение этой функции при помощи другой функции?

Tags: javascript

```
function myMove() {
    var elem = document.getElementById ("animate");
    var pos = 0;
    var id = setInterval (frame, 5);
    var counter = setInterval (displayTime, 1000);
    var time = Number (document.getElementById ("input").value);
    var dir = 1;
    var bounce = 0;

    document.getElementById("hitcount").innerHTML = "0"; 
    document.getElementById ("inputField" ).hidden = true;
    document.getElementById ("bttn" ).disabled = true;

    if (time < 10) { 
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "00:0" + time;
    } else {
       document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "00: "+ time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let id;
let counter;
    
function myMove() {
    ....
    
    id = setInterval (frame, 5);
    counter = setInterval (displayTime, 1000);
    
    ...
}


function stopMove() {
    clearInterval(id);
    clearInterval(counter);
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, дружище!


+ не смогу поставить, ведь репутация маленькая)

Comment: Можно просто галочку)